# How do I print the full value of a string variable in delve?

Tags: debugging, go, delve

I'm using the delve go debugger to debug some code. When I try to print a string variable, it gives me an abbreviated version.

```
(dlv) print myString
"my string...+539 more"
```

How do I get it to print the full string?

Answer (score 38):

The ability to configure the length of printed strings was recently added to delve. To see the full list of [configuration options](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/tree/master/Documentation/cli#config), run `config -list`;

```
(dlv) config -list
aliases            map[]
substitute-path    []
max-string-len     <not defined>
max-array-values   <not defined>
show-location-expr false
```

The one we're interested in here is called `max-string-len`, which you can see is currently `<not defined>`. To increase the length to e.g. 1000, run

```
(dlv) config max-string-len 1000
```

Now running `print myString` should print the whole string.

Answer (score 23):

Just to add to your answer, if you're using **VS Code** debugging feature, add the following config to your `settings.json`:

```
    "go.delveConfig": {
        "dlvLoadConfig": {
            "maxStringLen": 1024,
        },
        "apiVersion": 2,
    },
```

Answer (score 12):

Adding to the above answers, to have these configs applied each time you run `dlv`, you should be able to find the config file in ([see the sourcecode](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/pkg/config/config.go)):

- `$HOME/.dlv/config.yml` by default on MacOS
- `$HOME/.dlv/config.yml` by default on Linux. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is set then it should be in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dlv/config.yml`

For example, the relevant region in the `config.yml` file:

```
...
# Maximum number of elements loaded from an array.
max-array-values: 1000

# Maximum loaded string length.
max-string-len: 1000
...
```

```
Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) config -list
...
max-string-len         1000
max-array-values       1000
...
```

Comment: you can also run `config -save` from inside a running `dlv` instance (to save config values once you get them how you like them)

Answer (score 1):

### VSCode's Go Debugger

> #### I need to view large strings. How can I do that if `dlvLoadConfig` with `maxStringLen` is deprecated?
>
> The legacy adapter used `dlvLoadConfig` as one-time session-wide
> setting to override dlv's conservative default variable loading
> limits, intended to protect tool's performance. The new debug adapter
> is taking a different approach with on-demand loading of composite
> data and updated string limits, relaxed when interacting with
> individual strings. In particular, if the new default limit of 512,
> applied to all string values in the variables pane, is not sufficient,
> you can take advantage of a larger limit of 4096 with one of the
> following:
>
> - Hover over the variable in the source code
> - `Copy as Expression` to query the string via REPL in the DEBUG CONSOLE panel
> - `Copy Value` to clipboard
>
> Please [open an issue](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/new)
> if this is not sufficient for your use case or if you have any
> additional feedback.

[Source](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/5be771685c3220484a1ed0538396c0f3377250bf/docs/debugging.md#i-need-to-view-large-strings-how-can-i-do-that-if-dlvloadconfig-with-maxstringlen-is-deprecated)